# Конструкция switch

Tags: c

Пишу консольное приложение под Windows. В программе есть выбор действия в зависимости от нажатой пользователем клавиши. Всё организовано через конструкцию *switch*. К примеру:

```
char choice;

...

choice = char(tolower(_getch()));

switch (choice)
    {
        case 'i' : input_data(); menu();
        case 'u' : output_data(); menu();
        case 'r' : replace_data(); menu();
        case 's' : statistic(); menu();
        case 'q' : quit();
    };
```

Возник вопрос - как сделать так, чтоб если нажатая клавиша не входит в *case*, от пользователя всё равно ожидался ввод?

Comment: То, есть Вы хотите сделать так, чтобы ожидался ввод до тех пор пока, пользователь не введёт что-то из списка?

Comment: Именно так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:get_input
choice = char(tolower(_getch()));
switch (choice)
{
    case 'i' : input_data(); menu();
    case 'u' : output_data(); menu();
    case 'r' : replace_data(); menu();
    case 's' : statistic(); menu();
    case 'q' : quit();
    default:
        goto get_input;
};
```

или лучше так:

```
while (choice = char(tolower(_getch())))
{
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 'i' : input_data(); menu();
        case 'u' : output_data(); menu();
        case 'r' : replace_data(); menu();
        case 's' : statistic(); menu();
        case 'q' : quit();
    };
}
```

Comment: Вы сошли с ума или я? Что есть menu()? Если из menu() есть выход по return, то после выхода будет выполняться следующая метка. Возможна рекурсия непонятно какой глубины. Весьма странная конструкция.

Comment: На таких странных примерах сложно что-то объяснять. Проблема может оказаться совсем в другом месте.

Comment: alexlz прав. правильнее в каждую строку после "menu()" нужно добавить "break;" во избежания непреднамеренного выполнения нескольких case подряд.

Comment: В данном случае лучше подойдёт конструкция "do {} while"

Comment: можно предположить что menu в себе содержит exit и тогда break не нужны

Comment: Или siglongjmp(). На самом деле все это вертится вокруг кода в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

На C# подобную задачку делал: добавление/удаление/вывод/сохранение списка фамилий. В С в вашем варианте будет примерно так

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

char choice;
void input_data()
{
    system("cls");//очищаем консоль от предыдущих записей
    printf("input data\n");
    getch();//задержка перед очередным выводом меню
}
void output_data()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("output data\n");
    getch();
}
void replace_data()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("replace data\n");
    getch();
}
void statistic()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("statistic\n");
    getch();
}
void error()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("error\n");
    getch();
}
void menu()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("i - input data\nu - output data\nr - replace data\ns - statistic\nq - quit\n");
    choice = getch();
}
int main()
{
    menu();
    do
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 'i' : input_data(); menu(); break;
            case 'u' : output_data(); menu(); break;
            case 'r' : replace_data(); menu(); break;
            case 's' : statistic(); menu(); break;
            case 'q' : break;
            default  : error(); menu(); break;
        }

    } while (choice != 'q');
    return 0;
}
```

В Main самой первой вызываем функцию меню, которая нам пишет меню и считывает нажатую клавишу. Выходим из меню и выполняем в соответствии с case действие: i,u,r,s - вызов функции, q - выход, любая другая - сообщение об ошибке. Если q не выбрана, то выполняется нужно действие после которого опять вызываем меню и ждём нового нажатия клавиши. Никакой рекурсии тут не будет, т.к. мы выходим из функции меню обратно каждый раз, когда перехватили нажатие клавиши.